# how convert with startupScript from tmux to gnu-screen?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

```
# tmux Start Script Need To Work!!
if which tmux >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    #if not inside a tmux session, and if no session is started, start a new session
    test -z "$TMUX" && (tmux attach || tmux new-session)
fi
```

fine on arch wiki site:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux
it differences now then what it was before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen doesn't have an environmental variable like `TMUX` however `TERM` is set to "screen", so you can check that. Screen has a way of reattaching/creating all in one flag set.

`-d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.`

```
# screen Start Script Need To Work!!
if which screen >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    #if not inside a screen session, and if no session is started, start a new session
    [ "$TERM" != "screen" ] && screen -d -R
fi
```